# Is this possible Change tracking with updating with same value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have using `entity framework 6` and utilizing the change tracking feature,

```
var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(i => i.State == EntityState.Added || i.State == EntityState.Modified || i.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

1. First time I have a entity (table) where some property `value = false`.
2. I have updated the property with `value = true` and change tracking giving me the entity name (nice)

Now I'm updating the property with `value = true` again and this time I'm not getting back any change tracking entity name (I know EF feature)

Is there any way to get back the entity name always?

```
application.Enabled =true
container.UpdateObject(application);
container.SaveChangesAsync(Microsoft.OData.Client.SaveChangesOptions.None);
```

Comment: Do you mean you are saving the changes between the two edits of assigning `true`?

Comment: `false` to `true` and `true` to `false` give change tracking entity name, but `true` to `true` or `false` to `false` not giving result

Comment: @user584018, pardon me for stating what seems obvious to me, but... true -> true and false -> false *don't actually result in any change occurring*. Why would you have an expectation that there would be any change tracked that would trigger EF to return anything?

Comment: OK, just asking any possibilities to hook up