# EF: Is there way to disable change tracking only for one entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using `EF6` and have 2 entities which are going to update,

```
context.UpdateObject(entity1);
context.UpdateObject(entity2);
container.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now In change tracking I can see both entity coming,

```
var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(i => i.State == EntityState.Added || i.State == EntityState.Modified || i.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

Is there any way that I can disable change tracking for one entity `entity1`?

Comment: This seems like a very odd thing to try and do.  Can you give us more information about _why_ you want to do this?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There may be a better way to do it than fighting with the `ChangeTracker`.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941711 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var result = context.myentities.Where(...).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: No.  How to avoid change tracking NOT for all but only for one entity

Comment: context.myentities.Where(...).AsNoTracking().first();